# node.js, page not redirecting - statusCode, setHeader

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, redirect, response

It should redirect back to the "/" root url, but somehow it's not working properly.
it gives the 302 confirmation, but it wont get there

```
const fs = require("fs");

function requestHandler(req, res) {
  const url = req.url;
  const method = req.method;
  if (url === "/") {
    res.write("<html>");
    res.write("<head><title> Minha primeira página! </title></head>");
    res.write(
      "<body><form action='/message' method='POST'><input type='text' name ='message'><button type='submit'>Enviar</button></form></body>"
    );
    res.write("</html>");
    return res.end();
  }
  //console.log(req.url, req.method, req.headers);
  if (url === "/message" && method === "POST") {
    const body = [];
    req.on("data", (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk);
      body.push(chunk);
    });
    req.on("end", () => {
      const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
      const message = parsedBody.split("=")[1];
      fs.writeFile("message.txt", message, (err) => {});
    });
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.setHeader = ("Location", "/");
    return res.end();
  }
}
```

Redirect to "/" after solving /message

Comment: Yo likely have an async timing issue in your code. You issue the response before the req data arrived completely. Try to move the response to inside the `req.on("end")`

Comment: @PeterThoeny, i've tried that, but unfortunately works exactly the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use redirect to go to the home page like

```
res.redirect('/');
```